# Issue in uploading a file through http request using multipart/form-data in mule

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

Basically i have a curl command (which uploads a file to an API)which i want to execute this curl command through  mule.I am reading the file from read connector. Then using multipart/form data to convert curl command.and then passing it to the HTTP requestor.
BUt while running the application. The API returns the error as 'Input file is missing'.

error message

```
*            - - + APPLICATION + - -            *       - - + DOMAIN + - -       * - - + STATUS + - - *
*******************************************************************************************************
* mule_mediaupload                                 * default                        * DEPLOYED           *
*******************************************************************************************************

INFO  2020-05-25 19:56:16,835 [[MuleRuntime].io.04: [mule_mediaupload].so-file-http-request-sendFlow.BLOCKING @9753a94] [event: b17cd1f0-9e93-11ea-95ae-681401007098] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Provider Name Date
Planetearth,2015-05-01
RockMusic,2017-09-01
INFO  2020-05-25 19:56:17,082 [[MuleRuntime].cpuIntensive.01: [mule_mediaupload].so-file-http-request-sendFlow.CPU_INTENSIVE @1fea2bb] [event: b17cd1f0-9e93-11ea-95ae-681401007098] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: ------=_Part_2583_1939156918.1590416776933
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="params"

{Type:Import}
------=_Part_2583_1939156918.1590416776933--

INFO  2020-05-25 19:56:20,781 [[MuleRuntime].cpuLight.02: [mule_mediaupload].so-file-http-request-sendFlow.CPU_LITE @15368f21] [event: b17cd1f0-9e93-11ea-95ae-681401007098] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: {
  "success" : false,
  "processId" : "CA410762B598945B",
  "reasons" : [ {
    "code" : 57040122,
    "message" : "Input file is missing."
  } ]
}
```

below is the XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">


    <file:config name="File_Config" doc:name="File Config" doc:id="0272f407-da7b-46e7-a0e1-8f4edda4e3f9" >
        <file:connection workingDir="C:\Files\" />
    </file:config>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="00b795c8-285e-445c-9bb0-8001f2ffdaf8" />
        <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" host=" http://mysuperserver/" />
    </http:request-config>
    <flow name="so-file-http-request-sendFlow">
        <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler" doc:id="d6b797dd-7f26-41eb-8bb9-74456a4606fc" >
            <scheduling-strategy >
                <fixed-frequency frequency="1" timeUnit="DAYS"/>
            </scheduling-strategy>
        </scheduler>
        <file:read doc:name="Read" config-ref="File_Config" path="medialist.csv"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="2c9bb06a-e935-4469-8282-cef67adc5926" message="#[payload]"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="7cc45c6a-9326-49de-bea1-d4c9a29a6b26">
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output multipart/form-data
---
{
    parts : {
        params : {
          headers : {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
          },
          content : "{actionType:Import}"
        },
        file : {
              headers : {
                "Content-Disposition" : {
                    "name": "file",
                    "filename": ",medialist.csv"
                },
                "Content-Type" : "application/csv"
              }     
            }
        }      
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="c5a60159-e14f-436b-8952-efabc3bc07ac" message="#[payload]"/>
        <http:request method="POST" doc:name="Request" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration1" path="/media/upload/" doc:id="79ccd374-155d-40ca-b848-7e766337f5d3">
            <http:headers ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    Accept : "application/json",
    apiAccessKeyId : "username,
    apiSecretAccessKey : "Password"
}]]]></http:headers>
        </http:request>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="f2f8ffc4-3520-42d8-bca8-d45100adb144" message="#[payload]"/>

</flow>
    </mule>
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message, which may provide clues to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the content definition on the `file` part. Try this:

```
<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="7cc45c6a-9326-49de-bea1-d4c9a29a6b26">
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output multipart/form-data
---
{
    parts : {
        params : {
          headers : {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
          },
          content : "{actionType:Import}"
        },
        file : {
              headers : {
                "Content-Disposition" : {
                    "name": "file",
                    "filename": "medialist.csv"
                },
                "Content-Type" : "application/csv"
              },
              content: payload
            }
        }      
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
```